# What is the significance of an Ansible task reporting that something has changed?

Tags: ansible

I have a task that checks if my process is listening on port 8080 and only when the exit code is not zero, would I run `fail` with a message.

When the service is running, it reports that the status has changed. I want it to say `ok`. What does a `changed` status actually mean in Ansible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything that is dependent on something on the target will get the status "changed" when executed, even if it's just a shell command to echo something.

To suppress the "changed" status, you can add the following line to the task:

```
changed_when: false
```

This and other relevant things are listed on [the Ansible doc page for error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html).

Answer (score 36):

Ansible tasks should be [idempotent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/glossary.html#idempotency). Eg. if the task does not modify anything, it should return `ok` instead of `changed`. Most builtin modules and tasks are already, but for tasks such as `command` and `shell` you need to help ansible a bit.

For a task that does purely checking and does not modify anything, you should add:

```
changed_when: False
always_run: yes
```

The latter allows the task to run even in [check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html).

For the sake of completeness, such tasks are usually combined with another that does the actual modification, eg:

```
- command: check command that returns true when no change needed
  register: result
  changed_when: False
  always_run: yes
- command: modify command
  when: result.rc != 0
```

Comment: this should verified answer